# BeautifulSoup Scraping Unique web links and removing duplicated/similar links

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates

I am trying to scrape unique weblinks from a site with criteria being no duplicates.  Meaning same links ending with "/" or "#" are considered duplicates. This code I got from another stack overflow thread gives me the error: TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments.

```
import bs4 as bs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

BASE_url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.census.gov/programs- 
surveys/popest.html").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(BASE_url, "html.parser")

filename = "C742TaskMisajon.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "WebLinks\n"
f.write(headers)

all_links = soup.find_all('a')

url_set = set()

def clean_links(tags, base_url):
    cleaned_links = set()
    for tag in tags:
        link = tag.get('href')
        if link is None:
        continue
        if link.endswith('/') or link.endswith('#'):
            link = link[-1]
        full_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, link)
        cleaned_links.add(full_url)
    return cleaned_links

cleaned_links = clean_links(all_links, BASE_url)

for link in cleaned_links:
    f.write(str(link) + '\n')
```